# bibliographies from different directory

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to make a database bibliography file `library.bib`, then load it when I write a paper.

Though I already had a look [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6805/bib-library-file-in-a-different-directory-how-to-use-mendeley-centralised-b), it seems not for my case.

Using the below command, I though I found the candidate paths for .bib:

```
kpsewhich -show-path=bib
```

then it returned the below paths:

```
.;%AppData%/MiKTeX/2.9/bibtex/bib//;%LocalAppData%/MiKTeX/2.9/bibtex/bib//;
%ProgramData%/MiKTeX/2.9/bibtex/bib//;%ProgramFiles%/MiKTeX/2.9/bibtex/bib//
```

Note that I use absolute paths which do contain not `%AppData%` but `C:\Users\<User name>\AppData\Roaming`.

So I set **BibTeX Syncing path** in Mendeley as one of the above path: `%AppData%/MiKTeX/2.9/bibtex/bib//`(even this folder didn't exist, I made it manually), now I have a `library.bib` file in this folder:

```
%AppData%/MiKTeX/2.9/bibtex/bib/library.bib
```

I though that it should work if I import this on my `.tex` such that

```
\bibliography{library}
```

but it returns an error

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: myfilename.aux
The style file: style.bst
I couldn't open database file db.bib
---line 32 of file myfilename.aux
 : \bibdata{library
 :                 }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file myfilename.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "firstcitation"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

When I, however, assign the absolute path, then it works fine.

```
\bibliography{%AppData%/MiKTeX/2.9/bibtex/bib/library.bib}
```

Although there is a way to load my `library.bib` using absolute path, then there is no need to use TDS. Besides, I would like to use relative path not absolute path.

Can I use a relative path when I have `library.bib` in different directory from `myfilename.tex`?

Comment: Does kpsewhich find the file, i.e. what is the output of `kpsewhich library.bib`?

Comment: @RalfStubner if I hit `kpsewhich library.bib`, no response returns. if typing `kpsewhich -show-path=***.bib` it always returns same results what I wrote above.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20796/how-to-have-access-to-or-manage-bib-files-in-miktex. I found the suggestion to use a subdirectory particularly interesting. I have no MikTeX and cannot compare. The equivalent of your approach works with TeXLive on Linux.

Comment: @RalfStubner It works fine so far!! But one important thing is that it needs to restart the LaTeX editor when `.bib` has been changed. :) It does not matter at all so this is exactly what I wanted to do!! Why don't you write as the answer, then I definitely pick it up! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the suggestions in [How to have access to (or manage) bib files in MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20796/how-to-have-access-to-or-manage-bib-files-in-miktex). For MikTeX it seems to be necessary to use a subdirectory, e.g. `%AppData%/MiKTeX/2.9/bibtex/bib/mybib/library.bib`.