# Setting a path to a bibliography file in windows

Tags: bibliographies, paths

Creating a new bib file to save it in the same folder as my tex file is a mess, therefore I would like to have a permanent general bib file and be able to set a path to it when I am making a new tex file. (I am working with Windows 10).

I have tried:

1. Use something like \bibliography{"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/bibtex/bib/FullBib.bib"} (and without the .bib) but there is a problem with spaces (I would prefer to put the bib file in another folder, something like blabla/documents/math texts/FullBib.bib).
2. Use something like \bibliography{../../FullBib.bib"}.
3. Add as a root in Miktex C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/bibtex/bib/, refresh FNDB and try to use \bibliography{FullBib.bib} but I get an error in the aux file in the line \bibdata{FullBib.bib} and neither trying (1) works.

Point 1 was trying to follow [How to have access to (or manage) bib files in MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20796/how-to-have-access-to-or-manage-bib-files-in-miktex)

Can you explain like I was a toddler how to set a unique bib file and use it forever after? Also, I believe I am using Bibtex but I am not sure.

I am working with windows 10, Jabref 5.2, Texniccenter 2.02 and Miktex 2.9. My MnotWE is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
%More packages
\begin{document}

\cite{something}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{FullBib.bib}%or \bibliography{FullBib} or \bibliography{"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/bibtex/bib/FullBib.bib"} etc.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using the extra root is the way to go. But you probably need to check that latex can actually find it. Have you tried via the command line to run `kpsewhich FullBib.bib`. You mention you get an error, please cite the exact error message

Comment: And note that neither jabref or Texniccenter  are relevant here. Thoug I would probably recommend using something else than texniccenter as it does not seem to be activaly maintained (last updated in 2014)

Comment: @daleif The answer I marked solves the issue, thank you anyway. I was aware that Jabref and Texniccenter were probably not relevant, but I was not 100% sure. Also, do you recommend some latex editor in particular? Texniccenter seems to work fine, and as long as it is only an editor I thought it is not relevant to have updated versions (?).

Comment: If you like the editor to help you while you write take a look at texmaker or texstudio the latter has the same ancestor as texmaker but can do more. They also come with a build in pdf viewer with reverse search activated

Comment: The call to `\bibliography` should not include the `.bib` file extension. So `\bibliography{FullBib.bib}` would be incorrect and should be `\bibliography{FullBib}` and similarly for all other suggested calls. While TeX Live has accepted the superfluous `.bib` extension for some time, MikTeX was not able to find files in that case until recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a folder `mylocaltexmf` somewhere outside the texsystem. Your documents folder is a good place.
- in this folder create the subfolders `bibtex\bib\mybibs`
- Move your bib into the `mybibs` folder
- Go to the miktex console, settings, tab "directories" and add `mylocaltexmf` as a new root.

You can add more subfolders (e.g. `tex\latex`) and files to `mylocaltexmf`, when you do this you will have to update the filename database in the tasks menu of the console.

Comment: THANK YOU! This works smoothly. I assume something need "bibtex/bib/mybibs" to run, is this correct? Could I change some names of the folders or simplify this? Because mylocaltexmf is an odd name. Thank you again kind sir or madam.

Comment: you can choose the names of the "mylocaltexmf"  and "mybibs" folders, but the subfolder structure  bibtex/bib and tex/latex is important, this follows the structure of the main texmf tree and allows the tex programs to find their files. (and I'm a woman).

Comment: Understood, thank you madam.